# robloxplayerbeta vs windows10universal

Tags: windows, roblox

I do some project on ROBLOX application. Can someone explain me what is the difference between  two processes: **robloxplayerbeta** vs **windows10universal**? When will it be installed as robloxplayerbeta? Can I select it?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I don't think this is the right place for this question, since it has very little to do with the actual game.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Roblox already has a forum for roblox-related questions. You can find it at: https://devforum.roblox.com/ and ask this question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows10Universal.exe is the name of the executable for the Microsoft Store version of Roblox. RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is the name of the executable for the normal desktop version of Roblox downloaded from the website.

Comment: But why it's called "BETA"? Is it official exe?

Comment: Yes, it is the official exe and all roblox download from website bears this name @Chiko